# How to reliably reboot a windows PC with command line?

Tags: windows

I have to reboot 5 windows PC every week all located in remote location, I remote desktop to the machine and use command "shutdown -r -t 0" to reboot, but one of the PC won't come up until someone go to it and power down and up again, should I change any setting? its all Win7 PCs. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you set up a task in the Task Scheduler that reboots the computer every week?

Comment: this is temporary, we are going to schedule it, but have to check if a process is complete which I checking manually and rebooting for now.

Comment: Installing an IPMI on each PC would probably pay for itself quite quickly. Or even just one of those power strips with a network interface.

Comment: Type `shutdown /?` from a command prompt, or read the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732503.aspx).

Comment: The Windows shutdown process is only mostly reliable even under the best conditions.  There's no way to absolutely guarantee that the shutdown will complete other than being able to interrupt the power if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something different to do all of this automatically for you.

- Click "Start"
- Type "Task Scheduler"
- Click "Create Task"

Now, you can create a new task that will run every day.

> Here are a few important tips for setup:

- In the General tab, make sure you select the option to run the event whether or not a user is logged in.
- In the Triggers tab, add a new trigger and select Daily and the time for when the event should occur.
- In the actions tab, create a new action with a script of something like the following

---

```
shutdown -s -t 60 -c "System now shutting down. Save all work."
```

---

- In the conditions tab, change the settings so that the event will not occur while the machine is in use and delay the event until the system has been inactive for a specified amount of time.

---

Just on a note, this site is for programming, not IT support. Although this contains batch, this is more about IT support.

Comment: *Just on a note*: This question asks nothing about batch, so it's strictly a command-line question and (as you've correctly noted) it's off-topic here. Answering off-topic questions is a bad idea, as it encourages other off-topic questions (*I know it's wrong to ask here, but I can probably get an answer before it gets closed.*)

Answer (score 0):

Type shutdown /? from a command prompt

also you can create new task to restart you pc by start powershell and Type shutdown -s -t 60 -c

Good luck